# Cannot find name 'screenShotUtils'

Tags: c#, selenium, protractor

```
import {
    browser,
    Config
} from 'protractor';

//import {browser, element, By, by, protractor, ElementFinder, ExpectedConditions, WebElement, Key } from "@syncfusion/ej2-base/e2e/index"

var fs = require('fs')

describe("protractor screenshot", () => {
    browser.manage().window().setPosition(0, 0);
    it("Demo", async (done) => {
        browser.get("file:///D:/New%20folder/ej2-documenteditor-e2e/demos/CR_Issues/samples/height/image.html");
        browser.sleep(2000);

        function writeScreenShot(data: string, filename: string) {
            var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
            stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
            stream.end();
        }
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)');

        screenShotUtils.takeScreenshot({
            saveTo: "fullpageScreenshot.png"
        })

    });

});
```

Im getting [Cannot find name 'screenShotUtils'.]this error comes after importing in protractor .js.I have to take screenshot of the image in the website and compare with the already present image using protractor

Comment: what does c# have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have no module or object called screenShotUtils , you should be trying something like:

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.takeScreenshot

```
function writeScreenShot(data, filename) {
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
  stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
  stream.end();
}
var foo = element(by.id('foo'));

//of element
foo.takeScreenshot().then((png) => {
  writeScreenShot(png, 'foo.png');
});

//of entire page in viewport
browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) => {
  writeScreenShot(png, 'foo.png');
});
```

Comment: Yes but i dont have any locators on opening the website there is just an image I should take the full page image (Should scroll down) and compare two images.Pls share the code for the above details.

Comment: you din't need any locator to use browser.takeScreenshot

Comment: TypeScript error: D:/New folder/ej2-documenteditor-e2e/node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(8,68): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.  this error comes but its all fine in the code and 8th line

Comment: Pls see to the above issue